# Softlayer Swift Object Storage API - How to access a folder object?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

After searching through all of the documentation at developer.openstack.org/api-ref/object-store for an answer I have come up empty handed for a way to simply query object storage for the existing of a folder/directory inside a container.

```
curl.exe -isS  https://dal01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/v1/AUTH_d11/?container=JS&prefix=source&delimiter=/ -H  X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tk70f74664fd
```

This above is what I tried last to try to query the existence of "source" folder inside of container "JS". The container "JS" has the (virtual) folder "source" which has lots of other files and folders visible in the portal. Here is the response I keep getting ..

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Length: 0
```

Tried other suggestions in the docs to no avail

```
curl.exe -isS  https://dal01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/v1/AUTH_d11/JS/source -H  X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tk70f74664fd
```

This command above returns HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found.

Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Note:If run the same command with (an existing) file name at the end of the url, that works fine.

Comment: thx Nelson but thats the doc i consulted and tried the url posted above..
`curl.exe -isS  https://dal01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/v1/AUTH_d11/JS/source -H  X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tk70f74664fd` i.e. container/folder with no luck

Answer (score 0):

You only have to add the folder in the URL, for example you have the following structure:

```
├──container
       ├──folder
            ├──file

$ curl -i -H "X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tkb26239d441d6401d9482b004d45f7259" https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/v1/AUTH_df0de35c-d00a-40aa-b697-2b7f1b9331a6/container/folder
```

You can see some documentation here:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis